# Tcp Sockets, file transfert and low speed in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm transferring files over a Tcp Sockets connection, but it seems the speed is limited, here the way I send files over Tcp Sockets (TcpClient and TcpListener) :

On client side (Where CS is a CryptoStream which read a FileStream and TcpStr the NetworkStream of the TcpClient) :

```
do {
    numBytesRead = CS.Read(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
    TcpStr.Write(bytesToSend, 0, numBytesRead);
    iPos += numBytesRead;
} while (!(numBytesRead == 0));
```

On Server side (Where CS is the same than the on in Client side) :

```
do {
    numBytesRead = Tcp_NetStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, Tcp_Client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    CS.Write(bytesToRead, 0, numBytesRead);
    iPos += numBytesRead;
} while (!(iPos == Filesize));
```

But the maximum speed I got is always the same : 49164 bytes/sec but when I transfer over SFTP for example (to the same server) I've somthing like 100000 bytes/sec (which is my maximal upload speed).

I tried to set bigger or lesser buffer; I tried to set NoDelay property on true and false; but it don't seems affect the speed.

Any ideas why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to try the transfer without the encryption to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I just tried, and without I got the same limitation.

Comment: What is your Tcp_Client.ReceiveBufferSize size?